# no permissions for samsung galaxy 2s

Tags: android, permissions, adb

I just got a new *Samsung Galaxy 2S* phone to test my app. When I tried to ran the app, it shows AVD NAme N/A, target unknown and state ???

I have enabled debug mode and *unknown sources* on the phone.

I am developing using Ubuntu and I edited `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
```

changed its mode to a+r.

restart adb daemon:

```
sudo ./adb kill-server
sudo ./adb devices
```

However, it still shows:

```
./adb devices
List of devices attached
???????????? no permissions
```

Answer (score 10):

All of these commands you must do like a root. Go to terminal and type:

```
sudo -s
```

After that type:

```
gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

and paste this text:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"

Type:

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

After that (still as root) restart udev:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Now try:

```
adb devices
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What I had to do is disable USB Mass Storage mode. On CM9 , Go to Settings, Storage then hit Menu , then USB Computer Connection , and select Media device (MTP).

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue you have to replug the device ... adb devices could be ran as non root user ...

May this help too :
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.user/388013